# How can I edit the message of the email sent by Wagtail when a page is submitted for moderation?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm trying to edit the content of the email sent by Wagtail when a page is submitted for moderation, I've dug into the Wagtail source code and it turns out there is a function called `send_mail` which actually sends the emails to all the subscribers when a page is sent for moderation, this function is called by another one called `send_notification` which takes some notification templates (HTML and txt files) depending on the type of action (submitted, approved, rejected) of the page, those templates contain the email content and I haven't found the way to override the content of those templates from my Wagtail project.

If someone has done that before, I really appreciate your help.

Thank you!

I'm expecting being able to edit the content of the emails because I want to add some custom fields like comments.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please checkout the [tour], [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time Django is asked to render a template - including within Wagtail's notification email module - it will look for a template with a matching filename within each of the apps listed in INSTALLED_APPS in turn, and use the first one it finds. Therefore, to override one of the email templates from `wagtail/admin/templates/wagtailadmin/notifications/`, you need to:

- have an app in your project that's listed *above* `"wagtail.admin"` in `INSTALLED_APPS` in your project's settings file
- create a file within the folder `templates/wagtailadmin/notifications/` in that app, so that it takes precedence over the template provided by Wagtail.

The Django documentation has more details on [how templates are located](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.base.Template.render), and [how to override them](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/overriding-templates/).

For example, if you want to override the template [/wagtail/admin/templates/wagtailadmin/notifications/approved.html](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/main/wagtail/admin/templates/wagtailadmin/notifications/approved.html) (the email sent when a page is approved), and you have an app named `myapp` in your project that's listed above `"wagtail.admin"` in `INSTALLED_APPS`, you should create a template at the path `myapp/templates/wagtailadmin/notifications/approved.html`.

Comment: Oh that worked as expected, thank you so much!